# Need help with an identification of a Marvel character

Tags: marvel, character-identification

Some time ago I read a short fanart comic with a superhero that I don't recognize. I've tried to find him by description, by Google search, but all in vain.

I was going to write about him but even better, here are some pictures.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like **[Quasar](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Wendell_Vaughn_(Earth-616))**, AKA Wendell Vaughn.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasar_(Wendell_Vaughn)):

> Quasar (Wendell Elvis Vaughn) is a fictional superhero appearing in American comic books published by Marvel Comics. He is one of Marvel's cosmic heroes, a character whose adventures frequently take him into outer space or other dimensions. However, Quasar deviates from the archetype of the noble, dauntless alien set by such Silver Age cosmic heroes as the Silver Surfer, Adam Warlock and Captain Marvel (Mar-Vell) in that he is an everyman. He starred in an eponymous monthly ongoing series written by Mark Gruenwald that ran for sixty issues beginning in 1989 and has served as a member of The Avengers. In 2012, Quasar was ranked 36th in IGN's list of "The Top 50 Avengers".

> [image]
>
> <sub>*[Quasar Vol. 1 #35](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Quasar_Vol_1_35)* (June, 1992)</sub>

Comment: Yes. Thank you. This is him.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1vAN.jpg - perhaps this one from the cover of https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Quasar_Vol_1_26

Comment: I'm guessing the first image shows a time when he couldn't access his costume, and had to improvise with a yellow paint marker...